# What would be REST way to get relevant resources?

Tags: api, rest

Let's say I have an API to get a product given an product ID as: `api/products/<productid>`.

What would be a REST way to get **relevant** products given a product ID. I think I can use a query on the same endpoint as `api/products?id=<productid>`, but not sure if this is ideal or it might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice for making api url is `api/products/<productid>`.

for params other than id (generally for `filtering` or `searching` purpose), query params are considered `api/products?name=somename`

The detailed resource naming guide can be found [here](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)

Comment: Like you mentioned, solution for parameters other than id is pretty clear. My question is for the id parameter itself.

Comment: all right, to your question specific, api/products?id=<productid> is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be REST way to get relevant resources?

Answer this question: how would you do it on the web?

You might have a web page for the product, and then a link from that page to a new page describing the related resources, where each entry in that page would include links to the product page of the specific resources.

What we need to define for the client (or make it easy to discover) is how to find the links.

In the case of the web, we are typically using HTML representation of our pages.  HTML is special in that it has a standardized understanding of links.  For human consumers, we surround the link with context (typically, the contents of the A element); for machines, we should be a bit more precise about defining the rule.

For representations that don't have a standardized understanding of links, we need to do something else.  The most common answer is to use [Web Linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288), which is to say we put a description of the relationship between to URI into the headers of the response.

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they are consistent with the production rules defined in [RFC 3896](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).  So you can choose any spelling convention you like.

For instance, it is common to use spelling conventions that include key value pairs in the query part of the URI, because HTML GET forms can be used to describe links with that shape, which simplifies certain use cases.

Since REST doesn't care about your spelling conventions, you can use the extra freedom to address other problems (what spellings are easy for people reading the logs? what spellings are easy for people documenting the API? and so on....)